# Newbie help (in C) details inside

Tags: c

first of all I am a complete programming newbie, so I am sorry if there is something that does this really easily and I don't know of it, it is in no way my intention to be dumb.
[Also, sorry the programs are in spanish but I don't think the printf's really affect the whole logic thing.

Anyhow:
I made a program that evaluated a number and then got it as near as possible to the closest multiple of three, then I did the same for 5:

```
//cambia un numero al multiplo de 3 mas cercano 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(){ 
        int a; 
        printf("Escribe el numero que deseas redondear: "); 
                scanf(" %d", &a); 
        while(a%3 != 0){ 
                --a; 
                if (a%3 == 0) 
                        break; 
                a++; 
                a++; 
        } 
        printf("El multiplo de 3 mas cercano es: %d\n", a); 
} 

//cambia un numero al multiplo de 5 mas cercano 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(){ 
        int a; 
        printf("Escribe el numero que deseas redondear: "); 
                scanf(" %d", &a); 
        while(a%5 != 0){ 
                --a; 
                if (a%5 == 0) 
                        break; 
                --a; 
                if (a%5 == 0) 
                        break; 
                a++; 
                a++; 
                a++; 
                if (a%5 == 0) 
                        break; 
                a++; 
                if (a%5 == 0) 
                        break; 
                if (a%5 == 0) 
                        break; 
                a++; 
        } 
        printf("El multiplo de 5 mas cercano es: %d\n", a); 
}
```

---

Now I want to write a program that does the same, but takes the number of the multiple from the user. I wrote this:

```
//cambia un numero al multiplo de n (input) más cercano 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main(){ 
        int a, n; 
        printf("Escribe el numero que deseas redondear: "); 
                scanf(" %d", &a); 
        printf("Escribe el numero base para redondear: "); 
                scanf(" %d", &n); 
        for(a, n; a%n != 0; a++); 
        printf("El multiplo de %d mas cercano (A la derecha) es: %d\n",n, a); 
}
```

But of course this only makes it as near as possible from the right, and I don't know how (With n cases) to make it go to the closest number. The idea is this:

5 6 7 8 9 10
If we want it to go to the closest multiple of 5 and the input is 6-7 then it goes to 5, because that is the closest multiple of 5. If the input is 8-9 then it sends it to 10. The idea is always getting to the "closest" number. But I don't really see how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you could alternatively post the help in Java that would be more than sufficient as well. Since I know a bit java as well.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the modulus operator. 7%5 is 2 and 9%5 is 4. So if the modulo value is less than half your number you want to round down otherwise up. m=a%n; if (m<(n/2)) result=a-m; else result = a+(n-m);

Comment: Please give your question a descriptive title. Right now it tells us something about you and not about your question.

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to do this is divide, round, multiply.

Comment: Bart, I am terribly sorry. This is my first time posting on stackoverflow and I really fail. @Eddy, thank you, I had something around those lines in my mind but I couldn't quite land it. Thanks a lot! You're a godsend. Is there a way to give a "Vote up" or +Rep or something along those lines in this site? I would like to repay in anyway I can.

Comment: @Erick: You missed. You wanted the "add comment" link above the line instead.